# Can't search for all generated terms in lucene index

Tags: full-text-search, lucene

I'm indexing and searching code using a custom analyzer. Given text "will wi-fi work", following tokens are generated ('will' being a stop-word, is eliminated).

```
wi-fi {position:2 start:5 end:10}
wifi {position:2 start:5 end:10}
wi {position:2 start:5 end:7}
fi {position:2 start:8 end:10}
work {position:3 start:11 end:15}
```

When I search for terms wi-fi, work I get search results. However, when I issue any query (phrase/non-phrase) for wifi, wi, fi I don't get any results. Is there anything wrong with the generated tokens?

Parsed search queries:

For wi-fi  *(works fine)*

```
Lucene's: +matchAllDocs:true +(alltext:wi-fi alltext:wifi alltext:wi alltext:fi)
```

For wifi  *(no results returned)*

```
Lucene's: +matchAllDocs:true +alltext:wifi
```

For "will wi-fi work"  *(works fine)*

```
Lucene's: +matchAllDocs:true +alltext:"(wi-fi wifi wi fi) work"
```

For "will wifi work" *(no results returned)*

```
Lucene's: +matchAllDocs:true +alltext:"? wifi work"
```

### UPDATE

Found the issue:

```
public boolean incrementToken() throws IOException
{
    /*
     * first return all tokens in the list
     */
    if (tokens.size() > 0)
    {
        Token top = tokens.removeFirst();
        restoreState(current);
        **termAtt.setEmpty().append(new String(top.buffer(), 0, top.length()));**
        offsetAtt.setOffset(top.startOffset(), top.endOffset());
        posIncrAtt.setPositionIncrement(0);
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * if there are no more incoming tokens return false
     */
    if (!input.incrementToken())
        return false;

    Token wrapper = new Token();
    wrapper.copyBuffer(termAtt.buffer(), 0, termAtt.length());
    wrapper.setStartOffset(offsetAtt.startOffset());
    wrapper.setEndOffset(offsetAtt.endOffset());
    wrapper.setPositionIncrement(posIncrAtt.getPositionIncrement());

    normalizeHyphens(wrapper);
    current = captureState();
    return true;
}
```

In bolded line above I was saying

```
termAtt.setEmpty().append(new String(top.buffer()));
```

When i search for **wi**, i wasn't getting any results but **wi*** used to give results. Looks like this top.buffer() contains some additional junk which was resulting in weird behavior.

wasted a day on this :(

Comment: Can you see how exactly the query looks after parsing? I think you can just use its toString to see. Also, you have double-checked to make sure what terms are in the index?

Comment: Can you paste the debug output? It would allow us to see how the query is parsed. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#debugQuery

Comment: I have updated question with parsed search queries. @jpountz: how do i get debug query in lucene?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this output. It says to match against a field named "matchAllDocs" and against the "alltext" field. But anyway, since the difference between the working and not-working queries is so small, it looks like the problem could be with the index. Can you check manually that both the term "wi-fi" and "wifi" are stored in the index?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik : every document has a field called matchAllDocs with value set to true. alltext is the default field on which search is performed. when i see in luke i don't find wifi, wi, fi in index http://imagebin.org/207417

Comment: OK, so your problem happens at indexing time. As I understand, you have your own Analyzer that you want to be active at index time, so maybe you've just misconfigured the indexing process and your custom Analyzer is not getting through. BTW this matchAllDocs field is your addition, or something that Solr does automatically? I'm asking because its purpose should be filled by the MatchAllDocsQuery.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yeah, you are right about MatchAllDocsQuery. I have corrected my analyzer (one of the token-filters was commeneted). I have updated the parsed queries in question. Now i see terms in index as well, however problem still persists.  http://imagebin.org/207419

Comment: This is getting weird, now it would have to give results. All I can think of now is that somehow your search procedure is using a stale IndexSearcher, one that still doesn't see the change, whereas Luke sees the correct state of the index. Sorry, I'm at a loss with more ideas.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9900/discussion-between-naresh-and-marko-topolnik)

Comment: @jpountz I'm not using solr. by the way do offset-values affect search ?

Comment: No, they don't. They are used for highlighting. Regarding your error, since Token and CharTermAttribute implement/extend CharSequence, you should just write `termAtt.setEmpty().append(top)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just guessing without knowing your analyser or parser.

- Make sure the words wi,fi you are using in your search are not part of the stop words. Probably the stop list file is where you check
- Faceted search/Weighted search. Make sure you have not messed with these.
- After parsing/analyzing, make sure you do get the tokenized terms you are searching for.
- Make sure your terms are pushed into the index.